# C++: Garbage Collection

Tags: c++

I have a code like:

```
class A{
public:
void method1 (){
// do something
}
};

class B{
public:
void method2 (){
// do something
}
};

main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
A a ;
a.method1();
// free object a
B b ;
b.method2();
}
```

Now, before creating b object, I want to free memory alocated by a. Can anybody help me how to do that ?

Comment: Put it in its own scope. By the way, you should stop using GC terminology with C++. It doesn't have one.

Comment: C++ is supposed to produce no garbage to start with! (As per creator of C++) EDIT: The responsibility is fully yours, though. If you can't handle it, try another language.

Comment: @ActiveTrayPrntrTagDataStrDrvr Languages don't create garbage, Programmers do!

Comment: Then you'll be shooting a foot and blowing the whole leg. Another feature of the language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to add additional scope `{`,`}` , Since `a` is a automatic/local object, it will be destroyed automagically once the scope in which it is declared ends.

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    {                    //<--------------
        A a ;
        a.method1();
    }                    //<-------------
    B b ;
   b.method2();
}
```

This is also popularly known as **[RAII](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2321511/what-is-meant-by-resource-acquisition-is-initialization-raii)** in C++.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to do this, I think I should first point out this is a code smell. Destruction of an object shouldn't be a prerequisite for a new one being created. If it is, you're better off abstracting that away.

Here goes though:

```
main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   {
      A a ;
      a.method1();
   }// free object a
   B b ;
   b.method2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a new scope and automatic objects, but here is also an example of how to do it using dynamic allocation.

```
main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    A* a = new A();
    a.method1();
    delete a;

    B* b = new B();
    b.method2();
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: You might have misunderstood what was being asked.  Also: RAII.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you memory is allocated by a.

**for the code you pasted:**

```
g++ -gstabs -o a cpptest.cpp 
objdump -d ./a


0000000000400554 <main>:
  400554:   55                      push   %rbp
  400555:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  400558:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
  40055c:   89 7d ec                mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
  40055f:   48 89 75 e0             mov    %rsi,-0x20(%rbp)
  400563:   48 8d 45 ff             lea    -0x1(%rbp),%rax
  400567:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  40056a:   e8 13 00 00 00          callq  400582 <_ZN1A7method1Ev>
  40056f:   48 8d 45 fe             lea    -0x2(%rbp),%rax
  400573:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
  400576:   e8 11 00 00 00          callq  40058c <_ZN1B7method2Ev>
  40057b:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  400580:   c9                      leaveq 
  400581:   c3                      retq
```

In this exact case, your object a/b's memory is in Stack.
allocated by

```
400558:   48 83 ec 20             sub    $0x20,%rsp
```

as no member variable in your class, you class's instance will consume 1 byte (done by c++ compiler, for distinguish instances of the class)

you'll see the a's "this" pointer is transfered to _ZN1A7method1Ev (method1)
by

```
  400563:   48 8d 45 ff             lea    -0x1(%rbp),%rax
  400567:   48 89 c7                mov    %rax,%rdi
```

In this exact code case, you no need and can not free a's memory (on stack) before b.

- if you mean memory allocated by A. by malloc/new .
  then you should write free/delete code in A's destructor.
  and put a to an scope wrapped by {}, when a out of the scope the destructor will be called (which is automatically done by c++ compiler).
  like @Alok and @Luchian mentioned.
- if your memory is allocated in form of member variable, like following:

  class A{
      char foo[16];
    };

  when code is `A a;`
  then "foo" is allocated on stack as part of instance of A. you can not do anything.

  when code is `A *pa = new A();`
  then object is allocated on A, feel free to delete it.  `delete pa;`